# Installing new kernel based on DEB's

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, deb

I'm trying to test a proposed kernel for [Launchpad Issue 1556562: VIA C7-D machine "kernel NULL pointer dereference" in skcipher_recvmsg_async](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1556562). The proposed kernel is provided as a [collection of DEB files](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kamal/lp1556562.0/).

Based on experience with testing Ubuntu proposed kernels, I believe I need the linux image and extras (`linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb` and `linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb`).

So I'm clear and to avoid re-installing a base system (twice now), how does one install the kernel and extras using the DEB? Is it just like [installing any other DEB from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)?

I think an `update-grub2` will be required to get it into the GRUB menu. Are there additional steps that should be performed when installing a kernel by hand?

Or, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the small script I used to do it. In hindsight the script was probably overkill, but it gave me a foundation for reproducible results.

The order of the DEB files was not quite correct. On the first run, I got an error about unmet dependencies. The second run cleared the unmet dependency issue. (I did not copy the exact error message, but I should have to provide a more complete answer).

Running `update-grub2` manually was not required. Apparently there's a trigger to do it in one or more of the DEBs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kamal/lp1556562.0/linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kamal/lp1556562.0/linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kamal/lp1556562.0/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kamal/lp1556562.0/linux-tools-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb

dpkg -i linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb
dpkg -i linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb
dpkg -i linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb
dpkg -i linux-tools-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb
```

---

Removing the kernel after testing is a little more interesting because you have to use a package name, and not a DEB file. You also have to honor dependencies.

First, find the package name:

```
$ dpkg --info linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb | grep 'Package:'
 Package: linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic
```

Then, use `dpkg -r`:

```
$ dpkg --info linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic_4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562_i386.deb | grep 'Package:'
 Package: linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic

$ sudo dpkg -r linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic
(Reading database ... 126639 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic (4.2.0-35.40+lp1556562) ...
...
```

After all the DEB's have been removed, perform a cleanup, regenerate the grub menu and reboot.

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
...
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
...
$ sudo update-grub2
...
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```